# What's the meaning of "economic environment" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

Investors are showing more caution in the current ***economic environment.***

I interpreted it in 2 ways:

*1) Conditions in which economic activity take place*

*2) conditions and influences in which they carry on economic activity.*

Which one is correct, and are there any other interpretations possible?

Comment: I don't see a distinction between 'economic activity taking place' and '[people] carrying on economic activity'.

Comment: Also, "influences in which" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are right, however the first is more easily understood than the second one. But yes "something carrying out economic activity" and "economic activity taking place" is the same thing. The only difference comes in when you **define** that "something", e.g. people.

Answer (score 0):

**environment** is an overused nearly meaningless word when combined with a noun that already implies the meaning of the word "environment". It merely adds flatulence to prose. **The current economic environment** could be replaced with **the current economy**.

Merriam-Webster offers this relevant definition of **economy**:

> the structure or *conditions* of economic life in a country, area, *or period*

[my emphasis]

The word **current** tells which period. So the word **economy** has as part of its meaning the "conditions", which is what the word **environment** means.